# Windows Hello gives "The user name of password is incorrect" after changing user name

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, uac, biometrics, windows-hello

I have been using a USB fingerprint reader to sign in to multiple accounts using Windows Hello on my PC. I am logged into a domain account (without admin rights), with the other account being a local user (with admin rights), whose user name I changed using **Edit local users and groups** by right-clicking the user and pressing **Rename**.

After this change, I am no longer able to use Windows Hello to sign into this local account when running any application as administrator. If I use the finger associated with the local account, the UAC window will briefly flash with the *correct* full name of the user account, but then gives me a **The user name or password is incorrect** message, with the *old* user name.

- If I type in the new user name and password manually, it works fine;
- I have logged into the account, removed the fingerprints and PIN and re-added them, but the error persists;
- Before I changed the user name, I could use Windows Hello for both accounts;
- If I change back the user name, it works again.

How can I keep using Windows Hello to sign into this local account after changing the user name?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but maby someone is still encountering a similar problem.

My computer is in a domain and i have access to a local administrator account.
I had setup Windows Hello Fingerprint for the local account so i could elvevate my rights on the domain account.
After a name change of the local system, i wasn't able to use the Windows Hello Fingerprint anymore. The login always tried to sign in with the old local name. The problem persited even after removing the fingerprint and creating a new one.

Solution: Only removing the old fingerprint wasn't enough. I also needed to remove the Windows Hello PIN. After creating a new PIN and fingerprint, now everything works flawless again.

Comment: These question are never too old. I have the same problem. How did you remove PIN? The remove button is greyed out there.